# Passing variables to functions that use `enquo()`

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval, quasiquotes

I have a conceptual problem. I want to pass variables to a function that turns some of these variables into quosures via `enquo` (from the `dplyr`/`rlang` packages). However, I want to do so via other functions.

Consider the following, which has a lower-level function (the one that uses the `enquo()`) and a higher-level one that feeds into it. When it passes its variable `q` to `lower_function` (e.g., the user calls `higher_func1(mtcars, cyl==6)`), the value of `new_q` will be the expression 'q'.

**How do I preserve the user inputs of a higher level function so they can be accepted by `enquo()`?**  I know there are work-arounds where I would change `lower_function`, but I'm not interested in those. I'm interested in a solution that *doesn't* change the function with `enquo()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

higher_func1 <- function(df, q) {
  # Need to do something to `q` here
  lower_function(df, q, dplyr::filter)
}

lower_function <- function(df, qq, f) {
  new_q <- rlang::enquos(qq)
  f(df, !!! new_q)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this is possible is by taking `...` and forwarding them to the lower function. Named arguments have to be quoted and unquoted at each step.

Comment: How would one unquote it? Or am I misinterpreting you?

Comment: You pass `q` like this: `lower_function(df, !!enquo(q), filter)`

Comment: Ah great, that actually *does* solve it though, right?  That's just what I needed!

Comment: Ah sorry I had misunderstood the question, glad it worked out!