# Passing enquo expression to subfunction

Tags: r, tidyeval, quasiquotes

This question is related to [Passing variables to functions that use `enquo()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845318/passing-variables-to-functions-that-use-enquo).

I have a higher function with arguments of a tibble (`dat`) and the columns of interest in dat (`variables_of_interest_in_dat`). Within that function, there is a call to another function to which I want to pass `variables_of_interest_in_dat`.

```
higher_function <- function(dat, variables_of_interest_in_dat){
    variables_of_interest_in_dat <- enquos(variables_of_interest_in_dat)

    lower_function(dat, ???variables_of_interest_in_dat???)
    }
    
lower_function <- function(dat, variables_of_interest_in_dat){
    variables_of_interest_in_dat <- enquos(variables_of_interest_in_dat)
       
    dat %>%
         select(!!!variables_of_interest_in_dat)
    }
```

What is the recommended way to pass `variables_of_interest_in_dat` to lower_function?

I have tried `lower_function(dat, !!!variables_of_interest_in_dat)` but when I run `higher_function(mtcars, cyl)` this returns "Error: Can't use `!!!` at top level."

In the related post, the higher_function did not enquo the variables before passing them to lower function.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

```
library(tidyverse)

LF <- function(df,var){
      newdf <- df %>% select({{var}})
      return(newdf)
    }

HF <- function(df,var){
  LF(df,{{var}})
}

LF(mtcars,disp)  
HF(mtcars,disp)
```

the `{{}}` (aka 'curly curly') operator replaces the approach of quoting with `enquo()`

Comment: That works. But I am still wondering how/whether this could be done with enquo. In my real problem, the higher function actually uses ... as an argument, and then `vars <- enquos(..)`, and passes `vars` to lower function. Not sure how to use {{ }} with ...

Comment: alternatively, could you clarify how your functions would need to be modified to work with `HF(mtcars,vars(disp, mpg))`?

Comment: it already works with `HF(mtcars,c(disp, mpg))`